# How to get a user data in a related table using ion_auth

Tags: codeigniter-3, ion-auth

My database table is like this

```
users (the ion_auth table)
-id
-username
-password
-profile_id (the related field)

profiles (the related table)
-id
-fName
-lName
```

And in my view file, I want to echo the fName and lName by using this

```
<?php echo $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->fName ?>
<?php echo $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->lName ?>
```

Because when I use

```
<?php echo $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->profile_id ?>
```

this only outputs the id of the profile.

Comment: Maybe `<?php echo $this->ion_auth->user()->row(); ?>`?

Comment: Tpojka, what do you mean?

Comment: First, you don't need two tables with same data. Second you need e.g. `User_m.php` model which will be used for user data. You should make that model with its methods like `get($id)` and there you should put `$this->User_m->get($this->ion_auth->user()->row()->profile_id)`. That would be concept you could try to follow.

Comment: No. It's not the same data. I separated it for a purpose. Because, in my case, the profile table doesn't always need an account, it's for profiling only. And if the admin wants them to have an account to access the web, the admin just select those already profiled people to create an account. That's my case. :)

Comment: i worked with ion auth what i remember is ion auth only fetch data of its default columns.